# The given path's format is not supported (listing files)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move all files from a NAS to a cloud provider, which does not allow the char `?<>|/\\*:"` in its filenames, unfortunately some of the files do have these char in their filenames.

So I would like to fix these filenames before doing the migration, and thus I had the idea to list the forbiden filenames, but the forbiden char crash the Get-childItem command and I'm a bit stuck

Here's the command I use

```
 Get-ChildItem $myPath -Recurse -Force -File | Where-Object {$_.name -match '[?<>|/\\*:"]+'} | select fullname, name
```

And here's the output I get :

```
Get-ChildItem : The given path's format is not supported
Char, Line:1 : 1
+ Get-ChildItem path -Recurse -Force  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Is there a way to make the command fail but still tell me where was the file which crashed it ? Or is there another command or parameter to use to do what I want ?

Edit : For now I found a workaround, rather than mounting the distant nas with New-PSDrive, I sshed into the NAS and used the linux bash which was installed on it and supports these filenames but I am still interested by the answer to how to do it with powershell

Comment: This is unrelated to the regex. What is the exact value of `$myPath`?

Comment: My question is not about the regex, the regex is fine and the value of mypath is irrevelant, but if it can help you it's '.\ARCHIVES - PRE MIGRATION CLOUD\MKG' I know the command is fine since if I use it in a directory in which none of the files have forbiden char in their name, it works fine. My problem is if the files have forbiden chars, it crashes the command

Comment: I'm asking because it's unclear from your question whether `$myPath` refers to a location on the NAS or a local NTFS volume.

Comment: use a `try/catch` block and have the `catch` send out the error info.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sorry if it was unclear, it's a location on the nas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the the [common `-ErrorVariable` (`-ev`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable) parameter in combination with the [common `-ErrorAction` (`-ea`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction):

```sh
Get-ChildItem $myPath -Recurse -Force -File -ea SilentlyContinue -ev errs | 
  Where-Object {$_.name -match '[?<>|/\\*:"]+'} | select fullname, name

Write-Verbose -vb 'The following paths caused errors:'
$errs.TargetObject
```

- `-ea SilentlyContinue` silences error *display* (and continues execution as long as the errors are *non*-terminating, which they typically are).
- `-ev errs` captures the non-terminating errors in self-chosen variable `$errs`, which can be inspected later.

The `.TargetObject` property of the [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances collected in `$errs` contains the source object that triggered the error, which in the case at hand is the full path of the file-system object; `$errs.TargetObject` lists them all, across all error objects in the collection, courtesy of [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

---

**Update**:

- The above doesn't seem to help in the specific case at hand, as seemingly only a *single* error record is returned that doesn't have `.TargetObject` filled in and mentions only the *starting* directory of the recursive enumeration.
- The `Include *` approach shown below helped to at least narrow the problem down to individual *directories* containing offending files.

Adding `-Include *` to force explicit processing of individual files in each directory *may* help:

```sh
# Tries to find offending file names only, via `$errs`
$null = Get-ChildItem $myPath -Recurse -Force -File -Include * -ea SilentlyContinue -ev errs
```

Another option, given that you say that passing `-Directory` doesn't report errors, is to apply `Get-Item * -Force` to *each directory* and see if the offending file names can at least be narrowed down to specific directories:

```sh
# Tries to find offending file names only, via `$errs`
$null = & { Get-Item $myPath; Get-ChildItem $myPath -Recurse -Force -Directory } |
  Get-Item -Path { Join-Path $_.FullName * } -Force -ea SilentlyContinue -ev errs
```